# .Net inline Math calls producing infinity in x64 release

Tags: .net, x86, 64-bit

I'm curious if anyone else can reproduce this issue or if it's just an issue with my machine.  If I run the following code in a console application in Release mode with the "Prefer 32-bit" option unchecked under Project Properties -> Build, it returns infinity.  But as soon as I switch back to prefer 32-bit it returns 0.1.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
        t.Test(10);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public void Test(int logarithmBase)
    {
        double min = 0.9;
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow(logarithmBase, Math.Floor(Math.Log(min, logarithmBase))));
    }
}
```

The interesting part, at least for me, is that if I change logarithmBase to be a double then it starts outputting 0.1.  Also if I break the string of Math calls out into individual lines then it outputs 0.1 as well.

I can resolve this easily enough by doing one of the things I mentioned above but if anyone has an explanation for why it does this that would be great!

Edit: Here is the disassembly from IL Disassembler for the Main and Test functions with "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" unchecked.  I compared the IL for both the 32bit and 64bit versions and it looked exactly the same from what I could tell.

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
.entrypoint
// Code size       19 (0x13)
.maxstack  8
IL_0000:  newobj     instance void TestingLog.TestClass::.ctor()
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.s   10
IL_0007:  callvirt   instance void TestingLog.TestClass::Test(int32)
IL_000c:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.ConsoleKeyInfo [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey()
IL_0011:  pop
IL_0012:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main

.method public hidebysig instance void  Test(int32 logarithmBase) cil managed
{
// Code size       36 (0x24)
.maxstack  3
.locals init ([0] float64 min)
IL_0000:  ldc.r8     0.90000000000000002
IL_0009:  stloc.0
IL_000a:  ldarg.1
IL_000b:  conv.r8
IL_000c:  ldloc.0
IL_000d:  ldarg.1
IL_000e:  conv.r8
IL_000f:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Log(float64,
                                                        float64)
IL_0014:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Floor(float64)
IL_0019:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Pow(float64,
                                                        float64)
IL_001e:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(float64)
IL_0023:  ret
} // end of method TestClass::Test
```

Edit2: Disassembly from Visual Studio Disassembly window and the breakpoint is placed on the "min" variable definition.

```
            double min = 0.9;
00007FFC8A7242D0  sub         rsp,28h  
00007FFC8A7242D4  xorpd       xmm1,xmm1  
            Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow(logarithmBase, Math.Floor(Math.Log(min, logarithmBase))));
00007FFC8A7242D8  movsd       mmword ptr [rsp+20h],xmm1  
00007FFC8A7242DE  xorps       xmm1,xmm1  
00007FFC8A7242E1  cvtsi2sd    xmm1,edx  
00007FFC8A7242E5  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [7FFC8A724310h]  
00007FFC8A7242ED  call        00007FFCDA742B40  
00007FFC8A7242F2  call        00007FFCE9E13D90  
00007FFC8A7242F7  movaps      xmm1,xmm0  
00007FFC8A7242FA  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [rsp+20h]  
00007FFC8A724300  call        00007FFCE9EA3820  
00007FFC8A724305  call        00007FFCDA6E9E90  
00007FFC8A72430A  nop  
00007FFC8A72430B  add         rsp,28h  
00007FFC8A72430F  ret
```

Comment: Post the disassembly (uncheck "disable JIT optimization on module load")

Comment: I meant the native disassembly of course but it can't hurt to have the IL as well

Comment: Hopefully that's what you're looking for.  Sorry for taking so long.

Comment: Yes thanks, it doesn't really show much unfortunately, or at least I see nothing wrong here

Comment: Trying it online, in a 64-bit process, gives 0.1 as the answer. 32-bit fp-math is usually done with more precision than the 64-bit one but for your expression shouldn't make any difference. I can't see how to get infinity out of 10^[Log10(0.9)] even when considering the log base changing rule, there is enough precision even using float. Can you try it into another machine or by storing partial results into vars?

Comment: I've had 2 coworkers test my sample out on their machines and it produces the same behavior.  If you split up the Math calls into different statements then the issue no longer occurs.  It is very weird.

I logged an issue with Microsoft as it appears to be an issue with their compiler. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3140110/calling-series-of-math-functions-inline-in-64-bit-process-returns-infinity

I did attach a sample there but it doesn't seem to have updated yet.